# Remove index.php in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I'm trying to remove the 'index.php' from CI Urls.

I've tried many solutions, none of them worked. I've already set these variables in 'config.php':

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

And my current .htaccess is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^plugb.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.plugb.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|files|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The www prefix part works fine. But the 'index.php' part doesn't. If you want to check the webpage, here is it: http://www.plugb.com/index.php/home

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11106074/984422

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's instructions on how to do this in the [URLs Section of the CodeIgniter User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) under the section *"Removing the index.php file"*.

Answer (score 3):

Take your application folder out of the system folder and use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder_name/index.php/$1 [L]
```

It should work.