# Codeigniter controller/views 'pretty uri' not working

Tags: codeigniter

I'm a complete Codeigniter noob.

I think I have everything setup properly, and the pages display when I go to:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php/pages/view/my_page
```

but I get an Apache 404 error when I visit without the index.php file:

```
http://www.example.com/pages/view/my_page
```

Is there anything obvious I'm missing? .htaccess rules, or a change in the controller?

Comment: It's not clear to me from your question, but did you actually follow the steps required to remove `index.php` from your URLs?

Comment: @Colin: I'm not positive what those steps are. Are they located on the Codeigniter docs? I'm porting over a site from another server, so it's a bit of a guessing game for me.

Comment: [Yes, they are](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html). Also, see W. Kristianto's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the index.php file will be included in your URL

You can easily remove this file by using a [.htaccess](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) file with some simple rules. Here is an example of such a file, using the "negative" method in which everything is redirected except the specified items:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: And oh.. mod_rewrite must be loaded!